# Regex is triggering an 'Unextpected token' in my bash script , but it looks good as best I can tell. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: regex, bash

I have the following in my bash script:

```
if [ $YEAR_MONTH =~ ^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])$]
        then
                        echo "ERROR: Incorrct folder name format, should be <YYYY-mm>"
                        echo ""
                        print_instructions
                        exit 1
 fi
```

The regex is good as best as I can tell, but bash throws this error when I try run it:

```
myuser@myserver:/opt/myfolder$ ./fetch_logs_from_azure.sh list
./fetch_logs_from_azure.sh: line 51: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./fetch_logs_from_azure.sh: line 51: `                if [ $YEAR_MONTH =~ ^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])$]'
```

I thought I might need to escape the '-' but that didn't make a difference.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try adding space after $

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031 for further information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[ ... ]` does not support `=~`. Use `[[ ... ]]` instead.

```
[STEP 101] $ [ $PWD =~ ^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])$ ]
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
[STEP 102] $ [[ $PWD =~ ^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])$ ]]
[STEP 103] $
```